# VSCode: Display forwarding from docker container in Remote Development Extension

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

How to set up remote display forwarding from Docker container using the new [Remote Development](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release) extension?

Currently, my `.devcontainer` contains:

**devcontainer.json**

```
{
    "name": "kinetic_v5",
    "context": "..",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
    "runArgs": [
        "--net", "host",
        "-e", "DISPLAY=${env:DISPLAY}",
        "-e", "QT_GRAPHICSSYSTEM=native",
        "-e", "CONTAINER_NAME=kinetic_v5",
        "-v", "/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix",
        "--device=/dev/dri:/dev/dri",
        "--name=kinetic_v5",
    ],
    "extensions": [
        "ms-python.python"
    ]
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM docker.is.localnet:5000/amd/official:16.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y zsh \
    fonts-powerline \
    locales \
    # set up locale
    && locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

RUN pip install Cython

# run the installation script  
RUN wget https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh -O - | zsh || true

CMD ["zsh"]
```

This doesn't seem to do the job.

Setup details:

- OS: linux
- Product: Visual Studio Code - Insiders
- Product Version: 1.35.0-insider
- Language: en

---

**UPDATE**: You can find a thread on official git repo about this issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/550).